# What to do in Bangkok during midnight stopover

Tags: thailand, stopovers, bangkok

I have a connecting flight in Bangkok **Suvarnabhumi airport** which was suddenly rescheduled from 1AM to 6AM. Initially I had to wait 6 hours in the airport which is already a big deal, but now it becomes 11 hours.

Is there anything to do in Bangkok during the midnight of Monday? (7PM to 5AM)

Is there any public transport available at the time? I have been in Bangkok before and I had an impression that taking random taxi from the street is kind of scary because they hardly agree to use meter.

Comments:

Thanks all for your answers. I think I will go with booking a hotel with transfer to airport included. I am surprised to find out that it actually costs much less than I thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends a bit on which airport you are flying through and if you are doing international or domestic flights.

Personally I would find a room and get some sleep.  There are lots of economical hotel options nearby Suvarnabhumi Airport, most with shuttle service.  Don Muang Airport also has nearby lodging, though your choices are considerably fewer.

While Bangkok is active all night long, it is not really a tourist oriented scene after midnight.  Most activity centers around clubs and bars (though not all prostitution oriented as MikkaRin indicated, lots of discos and after hours drinking spots favored by young Thais).  There are some all night markets and street food vendors.  But as a whole wandering around Bangkok without an idea where you are going at 2 am is not the best idea.

You will find public transport from the airport to town, as you are arriving in the evening.  But going back to the airport will be limited to taxi, as many bus routes and the SkyTrain may not start early enough to get you there for a six am flight (domestic or international).

Answer (score 6):

From airport to center of Bangkok you may go by using skytrain. It's the fastest and easiest way.

After 9 pm, all normal places already closed. And at the midnight the only places are open is a clubs with prostitutes. Sad but true. However, if you search something more attractive than thai transvestites, I would recomend you to visit [Flowers Night Market](http://www.bangkok.com/shopping-market/pak-klong-market.htm) in old city.

It's two ways to get to airport after midnight - taxi or night bus. List of buses and bus stops you may find [here](http://www.suvarnabhumiairport.com/en/119-bus-bmta). You should remember that the road between airport and city center will takes 1.5 hour. I would recomend you to use taxi, because night bus drivers are completely crazy.

Comment: Technically, the train to/from the airport is not Skytrain. And, though 9-10pm is the normal closing time for department stores, a lot of (street) shops, cafes, and restaurants are open 24-hour or even only at night.

Answer (score 5):

I have never had trouble with Bangkok taxi-drivers.  Most of them are honest; the rest, tolerably honest.  Even if one does rip you off, their idea of a big score is what in New York would constitute bus-fare.

The SkyTrain does not go all the way to Suvarnabhumi.  Take the Airport/City train, which is about $3, and then get the SkyTrain (about 75¢) the rest of the way.

The tourist scene goes pretty late, so if you like bars and souvenir shops, you'll be fine until two or three.  Consider instead having a very nice meal -- Bangkok has some of the best food in the world -- and checking into an inexpensive hotel for a shower and a nap.

Also, and this might sound a little weird, but consider hanging out with *someone else*.  On the plane you'll be seated next to two tourists, and unless you are coming from Cambodia, you'll have plenty of time to talk to other passengers.  If you check into a hostel (consider [Suk-11](http://suk11.com)), there will be lots of fellow tourists there too.  Invite one or two to join you for dinner.  It probably isn't something you would do in your regular life, but there is a strong stranger-in-a-strange-land vibe among visitors to Thailand, and it make inter-farang sociability feel much more natural, much sooner.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would go to Khao San road or walk in Silom, Take a regular charter boat from the temple  Wat Arun to get a ride along bangkoks channels, and visit the temple also.  Walk around China town is also possible. And at the end take a massage to kill the time.

Boat and temple wat Arun first. 
Than go to China Town. 
After Khao San or Silom, i prefer Silom. 
Massage and than take a taxi to Airport.